# Passing an array to the Javascript Date constructor, is it standard?

Tags: javascript, date

This works in Chrome:

```
var dateArray = [2012, 6, 5];
var dateObject = new Date(dateArray);
```

And I get June 5, 2012. I also tried on an Android browser and I get the same results. However, the same does not work in Firefox or Safari. I could say:

```
var dateObject = new Date(2012, 6, 5);
```

But that would be July 5, 2012, as it should, and is also what I get with Chrome.

My question: is the first example part of the ECMA standard? Is it just that Chrome is more bleeding edge and could I expect other browsers to support it in the future? Or is it just some v8-ism that I should avoid for portability?

I've been trying to find references for this specific form of the Date constructor but could not get any.

Comment: Seems to be non-standard, probably safer to stick with the second form. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The ES5 spec details the [`new Date(value)` form](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2) of the `Date` constructor. In the algorithm for handling this form, `value` is converted to a primitive value by calling the [`[[DefaultValue]]` internal method](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2) of the object.

Converting an array to a primitive value is basically done by converting the array to a string. Converting an array to a string ([`Array.prototype.toString`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2)) is effectively the same as calling `dateArray.join()`.

Therefore, your call to the `Date` constructor will effectively look like this:

```
var dateObject = new Date("2012,6,5");
```

If the string can be recognised by the [`Date.parse` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), you will end up with a `Date` instance.

This form of the `Date` constructor is also [listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) as `new Date(dateString)`.

Firefox seems to fail when you pass an array, but it succeeds if you pass the string representation of that array. I would say that that's probably a Firefox bug, but I may be misinterpreting the ES5 spec.

Comment: "Probably" not as definitive as I hoped but this is the most plausible answer I've encountered.

Comment: @EdwardSamson - Yeah sorry, I tried to follow the spec as best I could, but it's a difficult document to understand fully! The fact that it doesn't work in Firefox means you probably shouldn't use it, even if it *should* work.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in ES6.

```js
let dateArray = [2012, 6, 5];
let dateObject = new Date(...dateArray);

console.log('Spread:', dateObject);
console.log('Direct:', new Date(2012, 6, 5));
```

Comment: This is awesome! Works natively atleast in FFox

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(
   Date, [null].concat([2011, 11, 24])
))
```

You use `apply` to call the new function you created using `bind` with array items as arguments.

Source: http://www.2ality.com/2011/08/spreading.html

Comment: can you please explain, what the role of concat here? Thanks!

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo: See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36408550/1762224). :)

Comment: @jure-triglav: In the note section https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_to_chain_constructors  MDN says ``` in this case you have to write something like: new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null].concat([2012, 11, 4])))() — anyhow this is not the best way to do things and probably should not be used in any production environment).```  Any idea  why?

Comment: I guess it's because the `Date` "class" can mutate or be modified in some way so this solution could end up in a runtime error. I'm thinking that this mutation could introduce a security breach as well.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Jure's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589301/1762224). I have cleared up [Sergio's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291206/passing-an-array-to-the-javascript-date-constructor-is-it-standard#comment57319815_26589301) in the comments by showing that the `null` is, in fact, the scope of the call.

```js
function newInstance(clazz, arguments, scope) {
  return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(clazz, [scope].concat(arguments)));
}

// Scope is not needed here.
var date = newInstance(Date, [2003, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6]);

// 1/2/2003, 4:05:06 AM (Locale = US EST)
document.body.innerHTML = date.toLocaleString();
```