# Table dates color in firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This code works perfectly to color dates that are allready in the past and colors dates within 2 weeks from now. But only in firefox and not in IE, can i adjust the code so it works in IE too? it has somthing to do with the rendering of `elem.style.color`

working [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wboco/dp4j4/)

```
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var parent = parents[i],
        children = parent.children

    for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
        var elem = children[j]
        if (j % 3 === 2) {
            var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
            var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");
            var prevTime = new Date(dateArray);
            var thisTime = new Date();
            var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
            var days = 1000*60*60*24;
            var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
            if (diffInDays < 0) {
                elem.style.color = "#996600";
            }
            else if (diffInDays <= 14) {
                elem.style.color = "#e50005 ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with an invalid date format for Internet Explorer.

Here is an updated [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp4j4/3/) that works also in IE. Using an array in the `Date` constructor in IE results in an invalid date. See also this question [Passing an array to the Javascript Date constructor, is it standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291206/passing-an-array-to-the-javascript-date-constructor-is-it-standard)

```
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var parent = parents[i],
        children = parent.children

    for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
        var elem = children[j]
        if (j % 3 === 2) {
            var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
            var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");     
            var prevTime = new Date(dateArray[0],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[2]);
            var thisTime = new Date();
            var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
            var days = 1000*60*60*24;
            var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
            if (diffInDays < 0) {
                elem.style.color = "#ffa500";
            }
            else if (diffInDays <= 14) {
                elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
            }
        }
    }
}
```