# pass in array of integers to create new Date not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of integers that I want to create a new Date with by using new Date but how can i get rid of the brackets so im just passing in the list of numbers? I have this:

```
var array = [2015, 3, 18, 2, 0, 0]
var newdate = new Date(array)
```

but it wont work because new Date cant have an array inside. Does anyone know how to make this work so im passing in:

```
var newdate = new Date(2015, 3, 18, 2, 0, 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `new Date(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5])`

Comment: @epascarello Suggested method doesn't work with Date constructor

Comment: @gurvinder372 Ah, meant to paste this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291206/passing-an-array-to-the-javascript-date-constructor-is-it-standard Grabbed the wrong one.

Comment: @epascarello yes this one works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spread syntax` does the trick.

```js
var array = [2015, 3, 18, 2, 0, 0];
var newdate = new Date(...array);

console.log(newdate);
```